# Let $P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$.For how many polynomials $Q(x)$ does there exist a polynomial $R(x)$ of degree 3 such that $P(Q(x))=P(x).R(x)?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$.For how many polynomials $Q(x)$ does there exist a polynomial $R(x)$ of degree 3 such that $P(Q(x))=P(x).R(x)?$

---

Let $R(x)$ be a third degree polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$
In $P(Q(x))=P(x).R(x)$,RHS is a sixth degree polynomial,so LHS must also be a sixth degree polynomial,
So $Q(x)$ must be a quadratic polynomial(let us say $ax^2+bx+c=0$)
But i dont know how to argue further and solve further.Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**: If $P(Q(x)) = P(x) \cdot R(x)$ for all $x$, then we must have:

$$P(Q(1)) = P(1) \cdot R(1) = 0$$ $$P(Q(2)) = P(2) \cdot R(2) = 0$$ $$P(Q(3)) = P(3) \cdot R(3) = 0$$

Since the zeros of $P$ are at $1,2,3$, we must have $Q(1),Q(2),Q(3) \in \{1,2,3\}$.

For each of the $3^3 = 27$ ways you can assign values to $Q(1)$, $Q(2)$, and $Q(3)$, there is exactly one possible polynomial $Q(x)$ with degree $\le 2$. How many of these result in $Q(x)$ being a quadratic polynomial (i.e. not linear or constant)?

Comment: We need to do away with $(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(1,2,3),(3,2,1)$ in order not to get $a=0$ of $Q(x)=ax^2+bx+c$@JimmyK4542.Right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I know that Q(x) must be of degree two, but how can we be sure that all those other 22 possible Q(x)s result in valid quadratics?

Comment: If the unique degree $\le 2$ polynomial passing through $(1,Q(1))$, $(2,Q(2))$, and $(3,Q(3))$ is not a quadratic, then it is either linear or constant, i.e. the graph of $y = Q(x)$ would be a straight line. You can check that each of the other $22$ ways of assigning values to $Q(1)$, $Q(2)$, and $Q(3)$ result in $(1,Q(1))$, $(2,Q(2))$, and $(3,Q(3))$ being non-colinear points.